# How does npm run a script to set system environment which can be used by another npm run script

Tags: node.js, npm

I set several scripts in package.json of npm, e.g.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "server:install": ". ./scripts/server-install.sh",
        "server:start": ". ./scripts/server-start.sh",
        "server:stop": ". ./scripts/server-stop.sh",
        "test:e2e": "jest --collectCoverage false test/**/*"
    } 
}
```

in `server-start.sh`, I will start dynamoDB service locally and need to set system environment `AWS_API_KEY` value. The value will be used in test cases when `npm run test:e2e`.

But, the problem is that the value I set for `AWS_API_KEY` in `server:start` can't be used in `test:e2e`. It seems that the variable set operation in server-start.sh will *not* change the system variables of current console/sessions.

I googled and tried like:

```
"server:start": "AWS_API_KEY=dummy . ./scripts/server-start.sh"
```

or by using [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

```
"server:start": "cross-env-shell AWS_API_KEY=dummy && . ./scripts/server-start.sh"
```

Both failed. The only left idea I can think of is to write the AWS_API_KEY to ~/.bash_profile. I don't want to do that.

Any help will be much appreciated.